# Problems with onContextItemSelected with two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contextmenu

I am using a `ViewPager`. I have two tabs and, consequently, two fragments that each one have their own Context Menu Options. My problem is when I click in Context Menu options in Fragment B, the method `onContextItemSelected()` in fragment A is called. How can I solve this?

I do the same as shown in the official Android documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    PositionClicked = info.position;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_edit:
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_archive:
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_report:
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_delete:
            Log.i(TAG, "Delete Menu Buttom");

            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Tem certeza?")
                .setMessage("Você está prestes a deletar sua Postagem!")
                .setPositiveButton("Deletar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        //ShowSwipeRefreshin();

                        delete_item(MongodbObjtoDelete);

                        DialogResp = true;
                        feedItems.remove(PositionClicked);
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null).show();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: add the code of you `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: i just added! @OussemaAroua. Thanks.

Comment: how did you add menu to context menu? how did u created it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can fix it like this :

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
if (manager.findFragmentByTag("frag1").isVisible()){
    // do fragment 1
}else{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of working ContextMenu

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        menu.setHeaderTitle("");
        menu.setHeaderIcon("");
        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ContextMenu);
        for (int I = 0; I < menuItems.length; I++) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, I, I, menuItems[I]);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();

        if(menuItemIndex == 0){
            //do something
        }

        return true;
    }
```

also check which views registered for Context menu.

```
registerForContextMenu(view);
```

Comment: This works too, but the solution from Oussema change a little bit less my code. Thank you so much!!